# WordPress - The “Transfer your site“ option is unavailable

Tags: wordpress, transfer

I will need to transfer my website to someone else. The instruction below seems does not work at all.

*https://wordpress.com/support/transferring-a-site-to-another-wordpress-com-account/

[Step 2: Start the Transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlPrG.png)

On the Settings > General page of my site I can't see the "Site tools" section and the "Transfer your site" option. Could someone please advise how I can find this option? Thanks a lot!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG9HE.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you've hosted in cPanel then the process is very easy. Make a cPanel backup using the wizard and later just send the file to new owner. You can use wetransfer for the job.

Additionaly, if you are a linux server user then you can make a command line transfer with programs like `rsync`. to transfer the database you can use `mysql -h remote-ip -u -p`
And before that you might need to add remote access to the new mysql database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).